# VBA: Find last row in a fixed number of ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I tried for a few hours to search and look for a possible answer. I am about ready to give up. I haven't been able to find someone with a scenario quite like the one I am asking, maybe I overlooked it.

I want to find the last row in a specific range. The ranges are `A7` to `A21`. I want to be able to enter input data from my form to the empty row within that range...

Here is where it gets tricky. I also have two other categories on the same sheet where I need to input data. Data may already be here, again I want to find the last row and then input data. Ranges `A27:A41`.

And the last category ranges `A46:A66`.

Hopefully someone here can help me out.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: if you use Range("A7").CurrentRegion.End(xlDown) you get the last cell in the region (or range) that contains the Cell A7. After that it is pretty easy to use Offset to goto the next row for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Define the ranges you use as tables in Excel on the sheet. Then in your code use:

```
Dim Table1 As listObject, Table2 As ListObject

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of the sheet the tables are on")
    Set Table1 = .ListObjects("Name of the table")
    Set Table2 = .ListObjects("Name of the table")
End With

Dim LastRowT1 As Long, LastRowT2 As Long
LastRowT1 = 1: LastRowT2 = 1
Do Until Table1.DataBodyRange(LastRowT1, 1) = Empty
    LastRowT1 = LastRowT1 + 1
Loop
Do Until Table2.DataBodyRange(LastRowT2, 1) = Empty
    LastRowT2 = LastRowT2 + 1
Loop

'If you run out of space and automatically want to add an extra row add
'the following code.
If LastRowT1 > Table1.ListRows.Count Then
    Table2.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
End If
If LastRowT2 > Table2.ListRows.Count Then
    Table2.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
End If
```

The Value of `LastRowT1 and LastRowT2` should be the row number (of the listobject) of the first empty row.

Comment: Great suggestion.  Tables (ListObjects) would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pointed in the right direction...

```
Sub Main()
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim r3 As Range
    Dim rFind As Range

    'Set your range vars
    Set r1 = Range("A7:A21")
    Set r2 = Range("A27:A41")
    Set r3 = Range("A46:A66")

    'Find the next empty cell and display the address
    On Error Resume Next
   'First range
    Set rFind = r1.Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "First open cell in " & r1.Address & " is " & rFind.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "First open cell in " & r1.Address & " is " & r1.Cells(1, 1).Address
    End If

    'Second range
    Set rFind = r2.Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "First open cell in " & r2.Address & " is " & rFind.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "First open cell in " & r2.Address & " is " & r2.Cells(1, 1).Address
    End If

    'Third range
    Set rFind = r3.Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "First open cell in " & r3.Address & " is " & rFind.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "First open cell in " & r3.Address & " is " & r3.Cells(1, 1).Address
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes that you're filling the cells from the top down (e.g. `A7` fills first, `A8` is next, then `A9`, etc.). If that's not the case, then instead of `.Find` you'd need to use a loop. You'll definitely need to adapt this to you situation, especially the logic for when all the cells in your ranges fill up.

Answer (score 0):

To make your request more generic (and hence scalable), you could create a function to find the first available row of any given range:

```
Function FindFirstOpenCell(ByVal R As Range) As Integer

  Dim row, col As Integer
  row = R.row
  col = R.Column

  FindFirstOpenCell = Cells(row + R.Rows.Count - 1, col).End(xlUp).row + 1

End Function
```

From here you could simply call the function over and over:

```
Dim row As Integer
row = FindFirstOpenCell(Range("A7:A21"))

Cells(row, 1).Value = "My Next Item"
```